# OpenMp slower after using std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now()

Tags: c++, performance, openmp

I have a code that run really fast by using OpenMp but without calculating the time elapsed using chrono.

Once I start using `std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now()`, the code runs way slower if I use OpenMp. If I turn OpenMp off, the code runs fast even when using chrono.

The code is compiled on a MAC OSX as follows:

`g++-4.9 -O3 -std=c++11 test.cpp -o test -lstdc++ -D__NO_INLINE__ -m64 -fopenmp`

The problem is clearly caused after calculating time using chrono. Many other posts are reporting that the code with OpenMp is slower than without OpenMp, but it seems that this is the case because of using chrono which nobody is reporting.

So these are the three cases just to make it easier to understand the situation:

OpenMp + No chrono = Fast code

OpenMp + chrono = Slow code

No OpenMp + chrono = Fast code

Comment: How much slower? Show your measurements and show your code!

Comment: Without OpenMp, I get the solution in 1.55 seconds. With OpenMp, I get the solution in 116 seconds. The code has nested time stamps using chrono. The code is so large (4000 lines) but I will create a smaller version and post it here.

Comment: Are you calling the timer routine in each iteration? Like 10000000 times in total? Try distilling the most relevant part of the code and pasting it here to make it easier for those of us, whose magic orbs have run out of mana.

Comment: How many times does your code call std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now() ? If you call it just once before start and once after to compare the times, then it is pretty evident that the creation of the actual timer has a huge performance impact. The simple solution is to not use it.

Comment: Use omp_get_wtime in OpenMP codes.

Comment: Show us the code, or at least a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)